# Azure-ad discovery keys don't work after some time

Tags: angular, azure

I have used open-id from azure-ad for my app and I am using a library called angular-oauth2-oidc, but after some months I am unable to log in, and a I have to perform a GET request to the URL for the discovery keys, copy them exactly as they appear, but also I noticed that they haven't changed and are the same but I have to do this everytime this happen.

Have someone experienced something similar and how did you solve this problem? There is no much documentation in the official docs from azure.

My app is in Angular 5.

Comment: Are you hard-coding the keys in your app?

Comment: @juunas Well if you consider doing copy-paste of them, then yes.

Comment: Hmm, would you be able to configure the authority URL in that library? Maybe it would be able to get the keys by itself, that's how backend libraries have worked.

Comment: Yeah, I had to. But if you don't add the discovery keys it throws an error, where it prints out that they aren't set.

Comment: Does your app differ a lot from the sample here: https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc? Maybe you could post the relevant parts in your question. Are you using v 3.1.4 as the author there says since you use Angular 5?

Comment: Well no. I am using v 3.1.4 because that was the released version when I started the project.